# K&R c++ indentation in emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

I'm using emacs 23. I've added this line:

```
(setq c-default-style "k&r")
```

to my .emacs file. It works but today I recognized a problem.
when I want to define a function inside a class(or struct) like this:

```
class CL {
    int f()
    {
        return 5;
    }
};
```

it indents that like this:

```
class CL {
    int f()
        {
            return 5;
        }
};
```

What is the correct form of this code in K&R (or Stroustrup) indentation styles? Is the emacs's form correct? if not, how should I correct that?

Comment: K&R didn't have much to say about C++, did they?

Comment: To quote K&R: "The position of braces is less important, although people hold passionate beliefs. We have chosen one of several popular styles. Pick a style that suits you, then use it consistently."